# c++, reinterpret_cast structure* to unsigned char*

Tags: c++, structure, reinterpret-cast

At first I'm sorry for my English:) 
So, I have a structure and variable

```
typedef struct
{
  GHEADER  m_Header;
  BYTE    *m_Buf;
  Addr    *m_Abonent;
}__attribute__((packed)) PACKET;

unsigned char* uc_ptr;
```

I need to send to some function unsigned char pointer argument. I tried to use `reinterpret_cast` to cast a pointer to `PACKET` type to `unsigned char*`.

```
PACKET* t_PACKET;
uc_ptr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(t_PACKET);
```

But then I tried

```
std::cout << *uc_ptr << std::endl;
```

I don't see anything. Why? And how to cast this correctly?

Comment: Because this most probably doesn't make much sense. This should be resolved using something else, casting is not for this purpose.

Comment: What are you expecting to see?

Answer (score 3):

When you use `<<` to output a `char` you get a single character written to the output. Many characters such as `\0` do not show up on the console.

Try this instead to see what I mean:

```
std::cout << static_cast<unsigned int>(*uc_ptr) << std::endl;
```

You'll need a loop to get all of the bytes in the structure.

Comment: @user1861137, it means the first byte of your structure is zero, as I suspected. That's a `NUL` character which won't be displayed on the console. If you can be more explicit about what you're trying to accomplish I might be able to help some more.

Comment: How can I get all bytes in the structure? May be something like this
while (i < sizeof(PACKET)){
  std::cout << static_cast<unsigned int>(*uc_ptr) << std::endl;
  ++i;
 }
but it isn't work. Only 0

Comment: @user1861137, use `uc_ptr[i]` instead of `*uc_ptr` in your loop.

Comment: Oh, it's time to sleep...
Thanks a lot!